# Spring MVC does not work with java configurations (the source server did not find the current representation for the target resource..)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-config

I try to create a simple Spring MVC and run in tomcat via eclipse ide with one simple controller:

```
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {
    
        @RequestMapping("/home")
        public String helloWorld(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "home university!");
            return "home";
        }
    }
```

my other configs:

webinitializer:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(MvcConfig.class, ServiceConfig.class,  AspectConfig.class, DaoConfig.class, DataSourceConfig.class);
        context.setServletContext(servletContext);
     
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispather", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

MvcSpringJavaConfig:

```
public class MvcConfig {
   
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "img.imaginary.controller")
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class MvcConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }
    }
}
```

structure:

[image]

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                                http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
            id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
   
</web-app>
```

my pom.xml:
[pom.xml](https://github.com/DenisYakovinov/SpringJdbcTemplateDao/blob/master/pom.xml)

and when tomcat starts and I try to open the app in the browser, I get
a 404 status and a description:

The source server has not found the current representation of the target resource or does not want to disclose its existence.

I tried to change the controller and the web.xml and other configs, but I always get this result

I can't figure out what I'm missing in order for my simple home controller to start correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `@Configuration` to `MvcConfig` class. also by referring to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html):

> Any nested configuration classes must be declared as static.

`MvcConfiguration` class must be static.